# jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:0.4.13:generate failed: trying to create the same field twice

Tags: java, json, maven

I am getting the below error stack while parsing the json schema and converting it in to java pojo.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:0.4.13:generate
>   (default) on project XXXXXXXXXXXX: Execution default of goal org
>   .jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:0.4.13:generate failed:
>   trying to create the same field twice: XXXXXXX -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:0.4.13:generate
>   (default) on pro ject XXXXXXXXXXXX: Execution default of goal
>   org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:0.4.13:generate
>   failed: trying to create the same field twice: XXXXXXX

Below is the maven  plugin details which I am using.

```
   <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.4.13</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/json-schema.json</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        <targetPackage>example.json.gen</targetPackage>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your JSON Schema which you are trying to parse? Sounds like you have a duplicated field in there?

---UPDATE---

Based on your comments you need to edit your json schema like this:

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "extends" : {
        "$ref" : "classA.json"
    }
}
```

This way you can extend from another json schema. However if you have two generated json schemas with the same fields there is afaik no way to "merge" them without manually editing or automated deleting of duplicated fields.

Comment: I know there are Duplicate values in JSON schema and I am looking for similar setting like XJC in case of XML, without causing failures it should generate the  java pojo.

Comment: Sorry, then I have no idea. Your question is a bit confusing. It sounds like you are asking what causes the exception instead of asking how to parse a json schema with duplicated fields without raising an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try to explain more, let say I have Class A and B and both contains field abc, and B is a part of class A. In this case I am getting duplicate error while parsing json schema.